# Install BlackBerry JDE plugin requests username and password

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Eclipse wants a username and password when I install the BlackBerry JDE.  I have a Blackberry account -- if I enter my account info it is rejected as wrong username and password.  What account is this looking for?

Comment: This is probably going to get closed as OT, but I think you need to create an account on the BlackBerry "developer zone" site. Is that the BlackBerry account you have, or do you have a consumer account attached to your device?

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/

Comment: I have two java developer acoount on developer zone.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience I faced such issuse when there were some problems with bberry servers. So after awhile it started work again.
Yes, you must use your bberry 'developer zone' account.